# Regex: Match various dimensional patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex to match several different dimensional patterns and their units.

Below are examples of the patterns. The numbers can be an integer, or a decimal. The dimensional separator can be: "x", "by" or "transverse by". The units are cm or mm

3.4 x 2 cm

3.4 by 2 cm

3.4 mm x 2.0 mm

3.4 cm x 2.0 cm x 2 cm

3.4 x 2 x 2.0 x 2 cm

3.4 cm x 2 cm transverse by 2.0 cm

3.4 transverse by 2.0 cm

3.4 mm transverse by 2.0 mm

4 cm

4.5 cm

So far I have the following:

```
(\d+(\.\d+|)\s?(x|by)\s?\d+(\.\d+|)(\s?(x|by)\s?\d*(\.?\d+|))?) (cm|mm)
```

But it doesn't pick up "transverse by", 3.4 mm x 2.0 mm, or 3 mm

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please specify the language, framework or library you are using. "Regex" describes a loose collection of independent languages with their own features and abilities.

Comment: using JavaScript compatible library

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using JavaScript or a Perl-compatible library. The following Regex uses pretty common features, so you should be good with most.

See an [example on regexr](https://regexr.com/70h36)

```text
((\d*\.)?\d+(\s*(cm|mm))?\s*(x|(transverse )?by)\s*)*(\d*\.)?\d+(\s*(cm|mm))?
```

### Explanation

Let's start with the end:

```text
(\d*\.)?\d+(\s*(cm|mm))?
```

This will match a decimal value (`(\d*\.)?\d+`) followed by an optional unit (`cm` or `mm`).

This will match simple text like:

- 4 cm
- 4.5 cm

Next is the prefix expression:

```text
((\d*\.)?\d+(\s*(cm|mm))?\s*(x|(transverse )?by)\s*)*
```

This breaks down into two parts:

The same expression we used before to match a number with a unit:

```text
(\d*\.)?\d+(\s*(cm|mm))?
```

followed by some separator (e.g. " x ", " by " and " transverse by ") text:

```text
\s*(x|(transverse )?by)\s*
```

Zero more prefixes are allowed, so you could match n-dimensional sizes:

- 4.5 cm x 55 mm by 105.3 transverse by 12.001 cm x 9 mm

If you want to constrain to 3-dimensional shapes, then instead of a `*` you can use `{,2}`:

```text
((\d*\.)?\d+(\s*(cm|mm))?\s*(x|(transverse )?by)\s*){,2}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a brain-freeze when it came to figuring out the entire pattern. How would I excluded numbers that are not part of a dimension, such as "24 year old", account # 34, series 23, 2.4 ml, or a date 02/23/2022?

Comment: No problem, @FritzHibbler. If you found this or any other answer helpful, be sure to upvote so that other visitors will more easily discover useful answers.

Comment: My 1+ here, thanks for your sharp eye!

Answer (score 2):

To get the full matches, you can write the pattern as:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s+[cm]m)?(?:\s+(?:x|(?:transverse\s+)?by)\s+\d(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s+[cm]m)?)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?:\s+[cm]m)?`
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part with alternations

  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:x|(?:transverse\s+)?by)` Match either `x` or `transverse by` or `by`
  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\d(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `(?:\s+[cm]m)?` Optionally match 1+ whitespace chars and either `cm` or `mm`
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/REixdM/1).

If you also want to match decimals starting with a dot like `.5 mm`

```
^(\d*\.)?\d+(?:\s+[cm]m)?(?:\s+(?:x|(?:transverse\s+)?by)\s+(\d*\.)?\d+(?:\s+[cm]m)?)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kw76sD/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to help me. It's very much appreciated!

Comment: @FritzHibbler you are welcome. If one of the answers helped you solve the issue, you could mark one as accepted and upvote the ones that were helpfull.